# Why getting items count in distributed storage is a costly operation?

Tags: api, distributed, distributed-system

I was reading that book about APIs called "API design patterns" by JJ Geewax and there was a section that talks about getting the count of items and he said it's not a good idea especially in distributed storage systems.

page 102

> Next, there is often the temptation to include a count of the items along with the listing. While this
> might be nice for user-interface consumers to show a total number of matching results, it often
> adds far more headache as time goes on and the number of items in the list grows beyond what
> was originally projected. This is particularly complicated for distributed storage systems that are
> not designed to provide quick access to counts matching specific queries. In short, it's generally a
> bad idea to include item counts in the responses to a standard List method.

Anyone has a clue why is that or at least gives me keywords to search for.

Comment: my first though - it has something to do with replicated storage and consistency guarantees (i am sure that does not answer any question). IMHO it is a bad idea to have such generalized statements. If you however consider an example and how it is build, you may find an answer for this particular system. I would say what the book means is that most of them are build such that they cannot provide an efficient count method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical database (e.g., a MySQL db with a few gigs of data in there), counting the number of rows is pretty easy. If that's all you'll ever deal with, then providing a count of matching results isn't a huge deal -- the concern comes up when things get bigger.

As the amount data starts growing (e.g., say... 10T?), dynamically computing an accurate count of matching rows can start to get pretty expensive (you have to scan and keep a running count of all the matching data). Even with a distributed storage system, this can be fast, but still expensive. This means your API will be spending a lot of computing resources to calculate the total number of results when it could be doing other important things. In my opinion, this is wasteful (a large expense for a "nice-to-have" on the API). If counts are critical to the API, then that changes the calculation.

Further, as changes to the data become more frequent (more creates, updates, and deletes), a count becomes less and less accurate as it might change drastically from one second to the next. In that case, not only is there more work being done to come up with a number, but that number isn't even all that accurate (and presumably, not super useful at that point).

So overall... result counts on larger data sets tend to be:

1. Expensive
2. More nice-to-have than business critical
3. Inaccurate

And since APIs tend to live much longer than we ever predict and can grow to a size far larger than we imagine, I discourage including result counts in API responses.

Every API is different though, so maybe it makes sense to have counts in your API, though I'd still suggest using rough estimates rather than exact counts to future-proof the API.

Some good reasons to include a count:

1. Your data size will stay reasonably small (i.e., able to be served by a single MySQL database).
2. Result counts are critical to your API (not just "nice-to-have").
3. Whatever numbers you come up with are accurate enough for your use cases (i.e., exact numbers for small data sets or "good estimates", not useless estimates).